# Why doesn't the button show up in the window

Tags: python, kivy

I don't know why when I run, the window won't show the buttons that I've added
Here is my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class StackLayoutExample(StackLayout):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b = Button(text="A", size_hint=(0.2, 0.2))
        self.add_widget(b)


class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```

and the .kv file is simply this:

```
StackLayoutExample:
```

Comment: you arent calling the class `StackLayoutExample` so they arent going to be added since the code isnt going to run

Comment: And the `kv` file should be named `thelab.kv`, otherwise it will not get loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote the typo `def __int__` but you need `def __init__`.

Comment: Good spot, I was about to ask what was different between the two lol

Comment: Oh my gosh,. I have spent almost two days on this. Thank you so much!